# Wrong response from Facebook Graph when fetching page profile

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-profile

I have a method to fetch page profile from facebook base on page username. The method as bellow:

```
  public static void fetchProfile(Context context, String username, Request.Callback callback){
            String graphPath = BASE_URL + username;
            Log.v("FacebookController","tungtran profile:"+graphPath);
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            Request request = new Request(session, graphPath, null, HttpMethod.GET, callback);
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
        }

  private void fetchAProfile(String username) {
        showWaiting("Loading profiles");
        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                FlyApp.log("tungtran profile - response:" + response.toString());
                hideWaiting();
            }
        };
        fetchProfile(this, username, callback);
    }
```

And I called in my class:

```
fetchAProfile("ChelseaFC");
```

It worked fine before but for some reasons It have not work some days ago.
The log in Logcat show me the graph path as bellow:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/ChelseaFC
```

And the response look very weird:

```
    {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"id":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.0\/ChelseaFC"}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

If I paste the path to Facebook Graph API Explorer or on browser the request return very DIFFERENCE response.

See the link
https://graph.facebook.com/ChelseaFC

I have spent several days to search the issue but I got no luck.

Could any body know what issues I have faced? Thanks in advanced for any help.

Comment: What it wrong? It looks like you got a graphObject back.

Comment: Yes, I got the response but it should be return full JSON information as the link:

[link](https://graph.facebook.com/ChelseaFC)

Comment: Why should it be JSON? You are using the Android SDK so what you get back is a Response object that you can read about at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Response/ . If you want the underlying JSON you have to do response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject() which will return a JSONObject

Comment: I'm not mean JSON or Response object.
I mean the DIFFERENCE response between execute in android code compare to Graph API.

 {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"id":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.0\/ChelseaFC"}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}

DIFFERENCE TO THE LINK BELLOW ON BROWSER:

https://graph.facebook.com/ChelseaFC

Comment: If you don't want JSON or the Response object. What do you want?

Comment: If you want a string that is the same that you found on that link do response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().toString()

Comment: "I'm not mean JSON or Response object. 

I mean the DIFFERENCE response between execute in android code compare to Graph API."

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Comment: @TranKhanhTung I'm not familiar with android but that's my opinion. The response example you show on your question is a "response object", and what you see using browser is a "json text", that's why people don't know why you compare "response object" with "json text". You should print out json text from response object so we can compare the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your replies,

I think we have misunderstood my issue.

If you see on the content of response you will see the difference.
When you click on the link you see many information. But in the Graph Object response it only has {"id":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.0\/ChelseaFC"}

Comment: @TranKhanhTung (I'm not familiar with android) I don't think response.toString()'s state={xxx} is the same with response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().toString(). What will print out if you use response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().toString() instead(Please try it first!)?

Comment: Yes, I tried your code and the result on log: {"id":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/chelseaFC"}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you anyway,

I resolved the problem.

The problem is in the String graphPath = BASE_URL + username;

We don't need it.

I changed the method as bellow:

```
public static void fetchProfile(Context context, String username, Request.Callback callback){
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            Request request = new Request(session, username, null, HttpMethod.GET, callback);
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
        }
```